# Problems With Simple TCP Client C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tcp, tcpclient

I'm having a problem with the TCP client that I am working on. For some reason, the client seems to be connecting, but it's not reading anything to the output box. Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string host = textBox1.Text;

        int port;
            port = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            port = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

        string sendText = textBox3.Text;

        Socket connectSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        connectSocket.Connect(host, port);

        System.IO.StreamReader connectionRead
            = new System.IO.StreamReader(new NetworkStream(connectSocket));

        connectSocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendText));

        while (connectionRead.Peek() > 0)
        {
            this.textBox4.AppendText(connectionRead.ReadLine() + "\r\n");
        }

        connectSocket.Close();
     }
```

I'm sorry about the object names, I did this in a bit of a rush. It shouldn't be too hard to understand though. I'm taking user input from textBox(s) and putting it into variables.

I seem to be getting stuck at:

```
while (connectionRead.Peek() > 0)
{
    this.textBox4.AppendText(connectionRead.ReadLine() + "\r\n");
}
```

Here, the program freezes for about 20 seconds, then unlocks with no output (the program does not crash).

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: Is the other side sending any data?

Comment: More specific, Is the other side sending NewLine char?

Comment: I'm unsure how to tell if the other side is actually sending anything. This is my first TCP project, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the problem lies in your assumption that if there is a character available in the stream (which you check with [`StreamReader.Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)) then you currently have a full line of content available as well.  There's no guarantee of this (you may have only received "Hello wo" of the data "Hello world\n"), so a call to `ReadLine()` would block until a `'\n'` is received.

However, I'm not sure why it's waiting 20 seconds each time before returning.  The default `ReadTimeout` for [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.aspx) is `Timeout.Infinite`.  Are you sure the connection is not being terminated by the server?  It may be configured to wait for around 20 seconds of "silence" before closing the connection (fairly common).

As an aside, you also may want to change your condition to `while (connectionRead.Peek() > -1)`. `Peek()` returns a character integer, and 0 is a valid value (`'\0'`).

Comment: I actually tried -1 earlier and got the same result. I think you are right about the server terminating the connection. How do you suggest that I test to see if I'm getting a full line of code? Or is there a way to simply output what I do get even if there is no '\n'?

Comment: A simple way to put everything you receive into the TextBox would be to change the while loop contents to `char c = (char)connectionRead.Read();   textBox4.AppendText(c.ToString() + "\r\n");`  That will put the data you get in the box character-by-character.  If you get garbage, you're probably receiving bytes outside the range of printable characters and you'll want to step through the code and see what the value of `c` is.  As for the server, that depends. What software are you talking to?

Comment: Ah, that was my guess :)  Google will terminate the connection if you don't behave like an HTTP client should.  Are you sending anything else after opening the connection?  [This page](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/http.shtml) shows more or less the simplest conversation you can have.

Comment: I actually figured it out! I just needed a carriage return after sendText. The rest of the code would have actually worked, but I do like your suggestion to read it character by character. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice! And yep, HTTP uses "\r\n" everywhere. Glad if I was able to help out.